# Distance between ecdf and cdf in R

Tags: r, statistics, cdf, exponential-distribution

I want to calculate the distance between **ecdf** and **cdf** with kolmogorov–Smirnov and plot the distance as function of the number of samples.

This is my code so far:
**How I created "exp_v":**

```
N = 10000
u = runif(10000,0,1)
lambda = 1
formula = (-1/lambda)*log(1-u)
exp_v = c()
for (i in 0:N){
  exp_v <- rep(formula)
}


x_t <- seq(from = 0.01, to = 10.001, by = 0.001)


y_t2 = 1 - exp(-x_t)

sortedArray = sort(exp_v)
sampleRange = sort(seq_along(exp_v)/N)

plot(sortedArray,sampleRange,type="l",lwd="5",color="blue")
lines(x_t,y_t2,type="l",lwd="1",col="white")
```

Now I want to calculate the distance between the "Theoretical cdf" and "empirical cdf"
Can someone help me with that?
y_t2 - is the theoretical cdf
sampleRange is the empirical values of ecdf

Comment: There is an ecdf function. The generation of an ECDF typically uses cumsum on sorted values.

Comment: Are you looking for `?ks.test()`?

Comment: I can not create a graph of the distance between ecdf and cdf as a function of the samples